# Parsing Text to double Array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, double, text-files

To run an algorithm I need to use as input a text file.
Input Example:

> 105.0,45.0,22.0
>       240.0,3.0,50.0
>       4344.0,4.0,55.0

On the algorithm i need to compute each row with each other(1st row with itself,2nd and 3rd row. 2nd row with 1st row, itself and 3rd row. 3rd row with 1st row,2nd row and itself). Output is a distance matrix with double values (input*input matrix so a 3*3 matrix in this case)

So far my code looks like this:

```
public class Distance{

public static double calcDist(int dim, double[] x, double[] y) {
//do computation here
//output printed here
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

String str;
String inputX;
String inputY;
double arrayX = 0;
double arrayY = 0;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/input.txt"));


List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while((str = in.readLine()) != null){
        list.add(str);
}


for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++){
    for(int j=0; j < list.size(); j++){

        inputX = list.get(i);
        arrayX = Double.parseDouble(inputX);

        inputY = list.get(j);
        arrayY = Double.parseDouble(inputY);

        double[] x = {arrayX};
        double[] y = {arrayY};

    calcDist(x.length,x,y);
    }

}
```

The distance method runs on its own fine, but i'm getting various errors on the main. Numberformatexceptions. Should be somewhere on the parsing I guess. Help appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Should be somewhere on the parsing I guess` -- Doesn't your compiler give you the offending line number?

Comment: Moreover what do you expect to get trying to parse `105.0,45.0,22.0` as double?

Comment: If you read all lines into a `String[]` is there any reason you don't use [the appropriate method from the JDK](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset))? Further, why copy a perfectly good `List` to an array only to loop over it? Finally, where do you split on `,`? One more thing, what's with calling `toString` on a `String`?

Comment: @devnull it would be the runtime actually

Comment: You're not splitting the strings up anywhere. You probably need this somewhere: `.split(",")`

Comment: If for testing i used something like:  double[] x = {105.0,45.0,22.0} and double[] y = {240.0,3.0,50.0} the Distance algorithm would work, just would need to dynamically compare each row.

Comment: `for(int j=0; i < stringArr.length; j++){` this also needs to be `j <`. If you didn't have this exception, you'd have an infinite loop

Comment: So my initially idea was to to directly paste the whole row(strArray] onto the double[] x and double[] y , and have a for loop around that for comparing each row

Comment: @user3086819 but there's no method that goes from `double,double,double` to `double[]`. You need to split on "," first to get a string array. parseDouble will error if it sees a non-number or a non-dot.

Comment: Offending line is  arrayX = Double.parseDouble(inputX);

Comment: I could probably use List<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
but I'm not sure if it can store the whole rows as one value

Answer (score 1):

your `inputX = stringArr[i].toString();` is apparently being `0` or something that cannot be parsed to `Double`. please check that and set some if-condition there if it makes sense for ya..

hope that helps